# Vim regex match multiple underscores

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to add some syntax colouring in vim for constants written in the standard uppercase form:

```
HELLO_WORLD
_GOOD_BYE_WORLD
```

when I go to http://regex101.com/ I am able to match these with the following:

```
/(_*[A-Z]+_*)+
```

but with vim it doesn't match anything.

/_ will match a single underscore but /_* will not match multiple underscores, it matches every character. After reading some of the vim regex documentation (http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html) it seems as though the underscore is used for extending matches across lines. However, all of the patterns listed in the documentation use \_ (an escaped underscore) as opposed to just the character.

How can I match words of this form?

And why does _* match every character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `\<[_A-Z]\+\>` will do what you want.

Accepted answer is matching underscores and capital letters contained in lowercase words.

Answer (score 2):

Vim has slightly different regex format, some key characters needs excaping, like `+` and `()`, here's your same regex formatted for vim

```
\(_*[A-Z]\+_*\)\+
```

For more info you can visit http://vimregex.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can also use vim's magic option \v

```
/\v(_*[A-Z]+_*)+
```

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the magic option. Given your regex I assume that it makes it so that I don't need to escape certain characters (`+` and `()`) like in Mohammad's answer.